# Is there an event handler on discord.py for username changes?

Tags: python, discord.py

I've looked on the documentation and all I could find was [`on_member_update()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.on_member_update), but  it's triggered only when a user changes nickname. Nothing happens if the username is changed.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `on_member_update` *is* triggered when a Member updates his username. Just tried it.

Comment: You're right! Maybe the documentation should be updated.